# DDNS and WoL via secondary router on a host network I don't control

Tags: networking, router, subnet, wake-on-lan, ddns

Short version is that I am trying to find a way to utilize wake-on-LAN to remotely (from an outside network) wake up a computer on a private subnet within a larger network that I do not control.

[Very simple network diagram to illustrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYedH.png)

Details:

I'm renting a single individual work space in a building, and that building provides internet to tenants. I have installed a router in my space that is connected to the building's router, to create my own private subnet (192.168.1.XXX).

I set up dynamic DNS on my router (TP-Link router using NO-IP as the DDNS provider), thinking/hoping that would give me a hostname address through which to send a WOL packet, allowing me to remotely wake up my PC from home, or anywhere else. My PC has a static IP address on my private network and I've set up IP/MAC binding.

However, when the router gives an IP address to NO-IP it provides its local IP on the host network (192.168.0.XXX), rather than a public IP.

I have been doing a bit of searching and all the solutions I've found require configuring things on the host router. That MAY be possible in my situation, but I'd rather not ask the building about setting up DDNS, port forwarding, etc. on their router if another solution is available.

So before I venture down that path, I wanted to lay it all out here to see if anyone has any ideas?

Does my router even have a public IP it could give to NO-IP that would make it accessible via hostname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WoL works on Ethernet addresses, not IP addresses.
Ethernet traffic by definition stops at an Ethernet segment border.
It does not traverse routers and is not routable.

If you can't get help from the building's network administrator for
sending WoL packet to your private network when solicited,
the only solution I can see is by using a secondary, always powered on,
"WoL packet sender" device such as RPi, xyz devboard, or old
laptop/smartphone.

Comment: Ah that extra bit of context is super helpful. Thank you, Harry!